# How to attach android.support sources to Android Studio 1.0?

Tags: android

How to attach android support library's sources to Android Studio ? I want to read the source code.

Comment: @Mogsdad add support lib source code to Android Source, not Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio click:

```
File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings... -> Maven -> Importing
```

Then check checkbox for automatically download:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the source code using Android SDK Manager, then in Android Studio, Click Navigate -> File, enter the class name, select the one fit you, type Enter, it will jump to the source code.